# Cast inputs to numbers in Angular2?

Tags: angular, property-binding

Is there any way to cast inputs to a component to a number automatically?

For example this component initialised like so:

```
<list-of-playlists limit="5"></list-of-playlists>
```

And defined here:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'list-of-playlists',
    templateUrl: 'list-of-playlists.html'
})
export class MyPlaylistComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() limit: number;
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(typeof limit);   // string
    }
}
```

Is there a way to cast `limit` to a number or integer automatically?

Otherwise I would have to type is as a string or any in `Typescript`, or to start the component by casting it to a number in `ngOnInit()`, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [Property Binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#property-binding):

```
<list-of-playlists [limit]="5"></list-of-playlists>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to http://victorsavkin.com/post/119943127151/angular-2-template-syntax (section Passing Constants)

```
<list-of-playlists limit="5">
```

is equivalent to (i.e., syntax sugar for)

```
<list-of-playlists [limit]=" '5' ">
```

That is, it always results in a string binding.
As @Sasxa already mentioned in his answer, use property binding to get the desired type.

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. It's a good link you provided.